# SQL minus operation using join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to construct a SQL query.
I have two tables `tblA(data INT)` and `tblB(data INT)` where `tblA` contains rows 1,2,3,4 and `tblB` contains 3,4,5,6.
What I want to achieve is I want take a join of `tblA` and `tblB` and in output I want contents of `tblA` which are not in `tblB`.

i.e. **minus operation.**

How can I achieve this using join in SQL Server 2012

Comment: Well, do you understand what a join means?

Comment: [Demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c3c4f/5)

Comment: @PeterRing I was a newbie then but such comments are always not welcome for newbies. You could have corrected in me in the answer.

Comment: Thanks @Jodrell.

Comment: @MaxRecursion you are right, my apologies

Comment: @PeterRing no worries, it all makes sense now. It was a stupid question :P

Answer (score 3):

Okay, use [`EXCEPT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx).

```
SELECT data 
FROM   tblA

EXCEPT 

SELECT data 
FROM   tblB
```

---

Using your teminology, UNION is add, EXCEPT is minus.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need join. I think you're searching for this:

```
select data from tblA
where data not in (select data from tblB)
```

You can also use `EXCEPT`

```
select data from tblA
EXCEPT
select data from tblB
```

Comment: @AshReva If you looked at the time you shouldn't ask that(unless you think i can see new post, copy, change form and post in 10 seconds). In fact Jodreil has done much edits on his post since first posted, while i haven't. Nevertheless, even if that was the case, i don't think that this is a helpful comment. The main point is to help the OP i think.

Comment: I am sorry really if it hurted you. I dont want to do into details now otherwise this will not end. I agree we should help OP. Sorry again.

Comment: It's not about hurting. It's just that the whole badge/achievement system has some fallbacks. No harm.